# Dynamic scoping of self and myself in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

When I run this code:

```
  to myself1
    create-turtles 1 
    let a "a"
    ask turtle 0 [
      show a
      show self
      ask patch-here [
        show a
        show self
        show myself
      ]
    ]
  end
```

I get this output:

```
(turtle 0): "a"
(turtle 0): (turtle 0)
(patch 0 0): "a"
(patch 0 0): (patch 0 0)
(patch 0 0): (turtle 0)
```

So inside the `ask patch` code block `self` refers to the patch, and `myself` refers to `turtle 0`.

This is what the NetLogo user manual (and example code) lead you to expect.

It's not clear to me why `self` should refer to the patch rather than to `turtle 0`.

Admittedly it's been a long time since I've written any Java, but my understanding is that `this` in an anonymous function refers to the object in which the function is embedded. In contrast, `self` in the code above refers to whichever patch is running the code -- rather than to the turtle in which `self` appears lexically. In addition, the local variable `a` *is* accessible from within the code block.

The decision to make `self` local to the code block, presumably to provide a way to refer to the agent that is executing the block, required that NetLogo define another way to refer to the calling context. That is the function of `myself`, as the example output shows.

More generally, it seems that `myself` refers to the calling turtle even when used in a separate function.

```
to myself2
  let a "a"
  ask turtle 0 [
    show a
    show self
    ask patch-here [ myself2' ]   
  ]
end

to myself2'
  ; show a
  show self    
  show myself
end
```

The output is:

```
(turtle 0): "a"
(turtle 0): (turtle 0)
(patch 0 0): (patch 0 0)
(patch 0 0): (turtle 0)
```

So `myself` is accessible from a separate function and refers back to the calling turtle. But the variable `a`, which would seem to be similar is not accessible. If `show a` were not commented out, NetLogo would issue an error message saying that `a` is not defined in `myself2'`. (In other words, NetLogo does not implement dynamic scoping in general even though these examples seem to suggest it does for `self` and `myself`.)

So, sorry for the long preliminary. My question is about the best way to explicate the quasi-dynamic scoping used for `self` and `myself` but not for local variables like `a`. Is it fair to say that `self` and `myself` are simply *ad hoc* special cases, or is there a better way to talk about it?

Comment: Use `self` to refer to whatever agent1 is actually "running" the code, e.g., because agent1 was asked to do so.  Use `myself` to refer to the agent2 that asked agent1 to run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.

The concepts that `self` and `myself` represent simply don't exist in other programming languages. Other programming languages just don't have the concept of "the agent executing this code", because the languages are not agent-based in the first place.

Any analogy with `this` in OO languages is distant at best and actively misleading at worst.

`self` and `myself` are both extremely useful as defined and if they weren't present in the language, with the definitions they have, you'd be in big trouble trying to code all sorts of things. That's the best short answer I can give to why they're defined as they are: they're useful.

As for the scoping behavior of local variables such as `a`, I think that's a separate question. You could certainly imagine trying to come up with some kind of agent-based definition of local variables, where `a` would be analogous to temporarily creating an agent variable. It isn't obvious to me whether such a design might be workable or even desirable, but in any case, we didn't do it that way and I don't think we ever even seriously explored the possibility.

Local variables in NetLogo work exactly the same as local variables in other lexically scoped languages. They don't participate in the agent-based nature of the language.

Comment: How about this? Let `self` keep its current meaning. Let `self-1` mean the same as the current `myself`, i.e., the caller of the current `ask`. Let `self-2` refer to the caller of the `ask` that `myself` is running. Let `self-3` refer to the caller of that `ask`, etc. Let `self-p` refer to the agent running the current procedure.  Limit the `self-n` references to lexically nested `ask`s within a procedure. That is, one can't use `self-n` to refer to an agent outside the current procedure. In that way it is all lexically scoped. For consistency, let `self-0` be the same as `self`.